# Element from list choosing by value of slider

Tags: c#, string, list, xaml, xamarin

I've got a problem with simple code(I'm newbie). Label should display an element from list with same index as value of slider. Code in XAML:

```
<StackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference slajder}"  HorizontalOptions="Fill">
    <Slider x:Name="slajder" Maximum="10" Minimum="1"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='{quotes[Value]}'}" />
</StackLayout>
```

And code in .cs file (C#):

```
    string[] quotes = { "one", "two", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10" };
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: to start with, your Slider isn't bound to anything

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: there is a sample here that demonstrates binding a Label and Slider: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#View-to-View_Bindings

Comment: I changed to: <Label Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='quotes[{0:F0}]'}" /> and now it shows in Label: quotes[1] instead the element from the list...